# Lavender (angustifolia) not handling the full sun well

Tags: plant-care, herbs, sunlight, wilt, lavender

[image]

I started these English Lavender from seed and they've been doing well a week or two after germination. Now that they have about 6-8 true leaves, whenever the sun is out, especially on a cloudless day, they would start to wilt/ drop like on the picture. They would go upright again after moving them into an area with less sun/diffused light. I water them before the sun is out so I don't think it's dehydration. What could be the problem here? Am I doing something wrong? I thought these Mediterranean plants love to be under the full sun in the middle of the desert, so why can't they handle full sun?

I would really appreciate any responses, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

They're seedlings, and seedlings don't cope with sun exposure, they need to be proper little plants with a reasonably well developed root system before they can deal with it. Keep them in dappled shade or shade (although a little early morning or very late evening sun should be okay, but not for long). This is the case for all seedlings, not just lavender. Once grown on properly, lavender likes full sun exposure for its permanent planting position.